# Counting of review are wrong on header and on page

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As the above screenshot you can see that the number of awaiting post that require review shows in the orange box and the number of Suggested edit, both are different. But before few days, whenever I checked the number count in orange box and Suggested edit always same.

So I think due to any maintenance there is generate this issue.

Hope so this post will focus moderators(mainly developers of site) about this bug.

Note: If any one feel there need to edit in post can edit freely or leave comment.

Thanks.